# Grouping opening hours together with start and end time respecting Interval

Tags: php, arrays, time

Say you have an array like this:

```
$timeslots[] = ['start' => '09:00:00', 'end' => '10:00:00'];
$timeslots[] = ['start' => '10:00:00', 'end' => '11:00:00'];
$timeslots[] = ['start' => '11:00:00', 'end' => '12:00:00'];
$timeslots[] = ['start' => '13:00:00', 'end' => '14:00:00'];
$timeslots[] = ['start' => '15:00:00', 'end' => '16:00:00'];
$timeslots[] = ['start' => '16:00:00', 'end' => '17:00:00'];
$timeslots[] = ['start' => '17:00:00', 'end' => '18:00:00'];
```

How would you go about processing this array to achieve the following end result:

09-11, 13, 15-17

This end result basically represents the shortest possible overview of which slots are available and grouping consecutive slots (where currentItem.EndHour == nextItem.startHour)

Now, intervals will always be the same within a slot, but the gaps can be completely random. To illustrate, the array might just as well look like this:

```
$timeslots[] = ['start' => '10:30:00', 'end' => '11:30:00'];
$timeslots[] = ['start' => '11:30:00', 'end' => '12:30:00'];
$timeslots[] = ['start' => '14:00:00', 'end' => '15:00:00'];
$timeslots[] = ['start' => '15:00:00', 'end' => '16:00:00'];
$timeslots[] = ['start' => '16:00:00', 'end' => '17:00:00'];
$timeslots[] = ['start' => '17:00:00', 'end' => '18:00:00'];
```

The intended result for this array would be: 10:30 - 11:30, 14-17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array with the start time being the key and the value being an array with the end time and the start time, though if we find that the start time exists in the array as the end time for another element, we update that existing element.

Then to output the groupings, use [implode()](http://php.net/implode) with an array returned from [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to get an array of the start times and last start time, unless those values are the same, in which case just get the start time.

```
$outputs = array();
foreach($timeslots as $timeslot) {
    $startToCombine = null;
    //see if the current start time exists as an end time for another element
    foreach($outputs as $start=>$output) {
        if ($output['end'] == $timeslot['start']) {
            $startToCombine = $start;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($startToCombine) {//if we have this end time, combine it
        $outputs[$startToCombine]['end'] = $timeslot['end'];
        $outputs[$startToCombine]['lastStart'] = $timeslot['start'];
    }
    else { //otherwise add the new timeslot
        $outputs[$timeslot['start']] = array(
            'lastStart' => $timeslot['start'],
            'end' => $timeslot['end']
        );
    }
}
implode(', ', array_map(function($start) use ($outputs) {
    if ($outputs[$start]['lastStart'] != $start) {
        return $start.'-'.$outputs[$start]['lastStart'];
    }
    return $start;
},array_keys($outputs)));
```

See it in action on [Teh Playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/6LUDFiWIHdTBOZdT).

#### Update

I [posted this implementation on code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/174993/120114) and while nobody (else) has (currently) answered, there was one comment that led me to revise my technique.
In [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/175012/120114), I changed the associative array format to key off the end time instead of the start time. Also notice the *foreach* was replaced with [array_reduce()](http://php.net/array_reduce) to iterate through the timeslots.

```
function combine($timeslots) {
    $outputs = array_reduce($timeslots, function($outputs, $timeslot) {
        if (array_key_exists($timeslot['start'], $outputs)) {
            $timeslotToCombine = $outputs[$timeslot['start']];
            $timeslotToCombine['lastStart'] = $timeslot['start'];
            $outputs[$timeslot['end']] = $timeslotToCombine;
            unset($outputs[$timeslot['start']]);
        }
        else {
            $outputs[$timeslot['end']] = array(
                'start' => $timeslot['start']
                );
        }
        return $outputs;
    }, array());
    return implode(', ', array_map(function($timeslot) {
        if (array_key_exists('lastStart', $timeslot)) {
            return $timeslot['start'].'-'.$timeslot['lastStart'];
        }
        return $timeslot['start'];
    },$outputs));
}
```

For a demonstration of this, checkout [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/UmUnhM7Xli39tU5x). When I ran the two code blocks on http://ideone.com and http://eval.in, both took ~0.01-0.02 seconds. The latter should be faster due to the fact that a nested loop was removed - i.e. complexity is *O(n)* instead of *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.